# Presto Cassandra Connector : number of connections

Tags: presto, scylla

I am looking into increasing the number of connections Presto makes to ScyllaDB. I am using Presto's Cassandra connector to connect to ScyllaDB. I don't see any property in the documentation that can be used to increase the number of connections. https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/cassandra.html

This is my scylladb.properties file

```
connector.name=cassandra
cassandra.contact-points=scylla1,scylla2,scylla3,scylla4
cassandra.client.read-timeout=3600000ms
cassandra.split-size=1024
cassandra.fetch-size=5000
cassandra.load-policy.token-aware.shuffle-replicas=true
cassandra.load-policy.use-token-aware=true
```

What is the default number of connections that Presto makes to cassandra/scylladb and how can I set this property? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the same logic as we do for Spark, reducing the `cassandra.split-size` to a lower number should make you benefit from the following:

- Coordination and data fetching is distributed among several coordinators
- Higher concurrency of requests, which translates to a higher number of connections between the Presto node/s and Scylla nodes

See how `cassandra.split-size=1` behaves and if needed raise to 10, 50, 100

Comment: I never tried this on Presto. Have always used it for Spark applications. I'll try it out. Thanks